# R: vectorized sample where the probability varies each time you sample

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization, sample

I'm trying to sample 10 values of either 0 or 1, with defined (but different) probabilities each time.

This does not work:

```
sample(0:1, size = 10, replace = T, prob = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1))
```

This does work:

```
sapply(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), function(x) sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(1-x, x)))
```

The 10th value is always 1, while the first value has a 1/10 chance of being a 1 - which is what I want to achieve.

Is there a vectorized approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sample from a binomial distribution:

```
rbinom(10, 1, prob = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1))
```